# Seeing if keys in two different tables match when linked by a foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables, match, players, and match_player - the third allowing a many-to-many relationship as each player has many matches, and a match consists of many players.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS match
             (id integer primary key,
             date text,
             winning_side integer)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player
            (id integer primary key,
            name text)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS match_player
            (id integer primary key autoincrement,
            match_id integer,
            player_id integer,
            side integer,
            foreign key(match_id) references match(id),
            foreign key(player_id) references player(id))
```

The side can be 1 or 0.

I want to see what % of games a player wins.

I figure a good way of doing this is a SELECT statement on the match_player and then counting the number of entries where side == winning_side. But of course winning_side is in a separate table.

I've been googling on how to easily do this, but can't fathom it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    mp.player_id,
    min(p.name) as name,
    sum(case when m.winning_side = mp.side then 1 else 0 end) * 100.00
        / count(*) as win_percentage
from
    match m
    inner join match_player mp
        on mp.match_id = m.id
    inner join player p
        on p.id = mp.player_id
group by mp.player_id
```

If you're really only interested in a single player it's pretty much the same thing. It wouldn't hurt anything but you no longer need the `group by`:

```
select
    min(p.name) as name,
    sum(case when m.winning_side = mp.side then 1 else 0 end) * 100.00
        / count(*) as win_percentage
from
    match m
    inner join match_player mp
        on mp.match_id = m.id
    inner join player p
        on p.id = mp.player_id
where mp.player_id = ???
```

And if you don't even care about the player's name then you can eliminate one of the joins:

```
select
    sum(case when m.winning_side = mp.side then 1 else 0 end) * 100.00
        / count(*) as win_percentage
from
    match m
    inner join match_player mp
        on mp.match_id = m.id
where mp.player_id = ???
```

I don't know how Sqlite handles numbers but usually you need to be careful to make sure your division is not integer division. So you probably don't want to wait to multiply by 100.00 until the end of the expression.

Hopefully that gives you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each match appears in `match_player` twice (or n-times), once for each player, then the `player` table is not actually needed.  Then, you can just use `avg()` to get the value you want, because MySQL has the convenient functionality of treating boolean values as integers:

```
select mp.player_id,
       avg(mp.side = m.winning_side) as proportion_winning
from match_player mp join
     match m
     on mp.match_id = m.id
group by mp.player_id;
```

If you want a value between 0 and 100, then multiply by 100:

```
select mp.player_id,
      100 *  avg(mp.side = m.winning_side) as proportion_winning
. . .
```